# Problems only with reading a file in NDK, writing to a file is error free

Tags: android, file, android-ndk

This simple program to **write** into a file is running fine in my emulator as I am getting a text file generated inside the sdcard(text file has HELLO WORLD in it) along with the given message on emulator screen.

```
jstring
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject thiz )
{
    FILE* file = fopen("/sdcard/hello.txt","w+");

    if (file != NULL)
    {
        fputs("HELLO WORLD!\n", file);
        fflush(file);
        fclose(file);
    }

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI (with file io)!");
}
```

But when I try to **read** the file using this program I am facing problems. It outputs nothing on the emulator screen or on logcat. As seen from the above program there definitely is no problem with the location of sdcard or with using FILE operations. How to fix it?

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_myproject_MainActivity_doSomething( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
        // Counts the characters inside file

        char ch;
        int cnt= 0;
        FILE* fptr = fopen("/sdcard/hello.txt","r");

        while((ch=fgetc(fptr))!=EOF)
            cnt++;
        fclose(fptr);
        LOGE("cnt: %d",cnt);

        return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from JNI (with file io)!");

}
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

This above code to read file works well in linux gcc but has errors working in Android. Changing it as mentioned by Andrew solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`, so this loop never terminates:

```
    while((ch=fgetc(fptr))!=EOF)
        cnt++;
```

because `ch` can never equal `EOF`.

Comment: If EOF is -1, it can be stored in a `char` -- assuming your compiler defaults to treating `char` as a signed type. I tried a simple example like the above just now, using linux/gcc, and it worked fine. Changing to `unsigned char ch` caused it to spin forever. Your answer is correct -- `ch` should be declared as an `int` -- but I'm not sure why Android is behaving differently in this regard.

Comment: @fadden: thanks, it was working well in linux gcc but giving errors in android. This error apparently made me to work on file IO for almost about a week now. Phew! finally got it to working.